# is it a good way to do RAID 1 (mirror)?

Tags: hard-drive, raid

I am new to doing RAID 1, I have a idea.
Due to RAID 1 must use two same size HDD, if one fail, I must buy a new one which is identical or lager than the old one.
So, is it better to use 95% of HDD, instead of 100%?

eg. two 1T HDD, I mirror 0.95T only.
so if one fail, I buy a new HDD, it should always larger than the old one...

is my idea ok?

sorry I was not saying my question clearly .
for example , different brand of "1T" hdd may have little different in size of bytes , if new hdd size is smaller. it will be troubles to rebuild raid ?

Answer (score 1):

RAID 1 is an identical copy, so for 1TB of space you must have 2 drives of 1TB. It will mirror entire disks, including partition table and partirtions.

If one fails, you can rebuild the RAID using another of 1TB or a larger one, but if you buy one of 2TB, RAID will only use 1TB and the extra size will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that expert in raid, but as far as my experiences goes with raid setting, if one fail, you just need to install a new blank one, yes, then the system will do synchronizing...
don't get what your 95% thing, because I think it doesn't matter if you use full 100%, as long as it is the same kind of hdd...

Answer (score -1):

As indicated by [this Asus support FAQ article](http://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1005589/) Intel rounds the capacity of the disk(s) down to 95% of the smallest physical disk. This allows for the variances in the physical disk capacities from different vendors.

So this is not just an ASUS thing (e.g. [Lenovo notice here](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht072811)).

For details see the Intel Rapid Storage Enterprise Technology 3.0 OEM Technical Guide: [Technical Product Specification](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fftp.micro-square.nl%2FPublic%2FDrivers%2FServer%2F%3D%2520SUPERMICRO%2520%3D%2FSuperServer%25205017R-WRF%2FRSTe_3.2.0.1135%2FRSTe3.0-TPS.pdf&ei=Y0frU92pJcTqyQPLwIKoCA&usg=AFQjCNEl75Y7Jr9SF41IhOn9uEPGX06YHA&sig2=x86sFqlKocG3KQbE9zaf5Q&bvm=bv.72938740,d.bGQ&cad=rja) PDF download.